# How does the shelf life of dry ingredients depend on humidity levels?

Tags: storage, dry

Is there any data on the shelf-life of dry ingredients (dry vegetables, for example) depending on the humidity levels during the storage?

Let's say I bought Freeze-Dried Green Peas and moved them from their original packages to a storage box with a specific humidity level (for example, 25%). What will be their shelf-life? Days? Weeks? Months?

Comment: Ingredients you've dried yourself or packaged and store bought? In either case more information will help you get a better answer.  If you dried...what veg....how did you dry...what are the storage conditions...if you purchased...brand and how they are packaged.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm looking for some general data. Let's say I bought Freeze-Dried Green Peas and moved them from their original packages to a storage box with a certain RH (for example, 25%). What will be their shelf-life? Days? Weeks? Months?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone can provide the specific detail you are asking for (but correct me if I am wrong). There is a difference between drying a freeze drying.  Dried vegetables have a 4 month to one year shelf life.  Freeze drying increases shelf life dramatically...[up to 25 years](https://www.ivins.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/RCP-Freeze-drying-vs-Dehydrating-1.pdf).  Cool temperatures and reducing light exposure also helps.  Often packaged, freeze dried foods contain a non-edible desiccant packet to absorb any moisture.  If you are switching containers, be sure to include that (or, if a desiccant packet is not included, obtain and include it yourself...they are available on Amazon).  Do not eat the desiccant packet. It's sole purpose is to absorb moisture.  In the end, I would leave in original packaging, but if you have to move to alternate storage, work cleanly, then keep dry and cool.  It should not impact shelf life all that much.

Comment: Good answer. I agree, no general data on this sort of thing, would depend on exact processing method and exact storage method after opening. Sometimes the packages will also include anti-oxidant packets, especially if they have something containing oils.